# c# how to store .dat file containing white spaces between text to sql server database in rows and columns as it is

Tags: c#, sql-server

c# how to store .dat file containing white spaces between text to sql server database in rows and columns as it is

```
1   2014-03-13 15:21:32 1   0   1   0
24  2015-02-09 16:37:52 1   0   1   0
16  2015-02-09 16:40:10 1   0   1   0
11  2015-02-09 16:41:17 1   0   1   0
```

Comment: Perhaps you could show what you've tried so far and someone could point you in the right direction?

Comment: What .dat file? Use import function in SSMS?

Comment: Man, I'm confused. So you want to save a CSV file with whitespace as the field separator? I get that #2 is a DateTime, but what are the others? #1 id? the rest bool? 'Cause that's not binary (.dat)

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to store the .dat File to recreate and use it later on, you can store it as a BLOB:

in ADO.NET:

```
   SqlParameter param=new SqlParameter("@yourdatFile", SqlDbType.VarBinary);
   param.Value=<YourDatFileAsBinary>;
```

Your sql field will be varbinary(max).
Later on read it back from DB as Binary and stream it into a file.

If your goal is to load the information between the whitespaces in your dat-file into separate columns in your database table or even create a new table dynamically with different count of columns for further use, you should read your file first via Split, then you can dynamically create your table and insert.

For example:

```
        var f = File.ReadAllText("path");
        var splitted = f.Split(null); // splits by whitespace

        // If you want to create a dynamic table for your .dat file information, since you don't know how many columns will be needed.
        // I do not recommend this way!! Your database scheme should not be modified dynamically.
        var createSql = "CREATE TABLE yourTable ( ";
        foreach (var entry in splitted)
        {
            createSql += string.Format("{0} nvarchar(100), ", entry);
        }

        createSql += " );";


        var insertSql = "INSERT INTO yourTable VALUES ( ";
        foreach (var entry in splitted)
        {
            insertSql += string.Format("{0}, ", entry);
        }

        insertSql += " );";

        // run these two scripts via ado on your DB
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        StreamReader r = new StreamReader(f);
         {

           conn.Open();
           while (!r.EndOfStream)
                    {
                        var s = r.ReadLine().Split('\t');
                        string temp = s[1];
                        var temp1 = temp.Split(null);

                        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into attendance2 values('" + s[0] + "','" + temp1[0] + "','" + temp1[1] + "','" + s[2] + "','" + s[3] + "','" + s[4] + "','" + s[5] + "')", conn);
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }

                    conn.Close();
```